# sed replace xml tag

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to replace value inside a tag in an xml file using sed.

```
<version> xxxx-SS </version>
```

I want to replace xxxx-SS with some shell variable $ver .
The final result should be

```
<version>$ver</version>
```

The sed command should also quit after replacing the first instance.

So far I have been able to only append to the xxxx-SS and not been able to quit after the first match.

```
sed 's#\(<version>\)*\(</version>\)#\1'$ver'\2#g' test.xml
```

This only appends the value between -SNAPSHOT tag.Basically makes it xxxx-SS$ver

Comment: add the code you tried to question... using regex for xml is not advised, use xml aware parsers

Comment: Kindly check now

Comment: The regex used above will not work: change at least `*` into `.*`, but better look below at the solution with **xmlstarlet**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use `awk`, it would more simple to achieve what you desire,

```
$ cp test.xml test_orig.xml

$ awk '/<version> xxxx-SS <\/version>/{gsub(/<version> xxxx-SS <\/version>/,"<version> $ver </version>",$0)}1' test_orig.xml > test.xml
$ cat test.xml
...
<version> $ver </version>
...

$ rm test_orig.xml
```

The command would substitute `xxxx-SS` to `test` (modify the var value to what you want)

Comment: It is only adding after the tag and not in between. Also it is not writing to the same file.

Comment: @KshitijGarg please edit the question to show your expected result.

Comment: Kindly check now

Comment: Ok, I misunderstand you, hold a sec. I'll modify my answer as you desire.

Comment: Honestly, I prefer the **xmlstarlet** solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using xml/html parsers is the right way to manipulate xml/html documents. Don't use sed/awk tools for such cases.

[***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320) solution:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//version[1]" -v $ver test.xml
```

- `ed` - edit mode
- `-u` - update action
- `//version[1]` - xpath expression to select the first `version` tag
- `-v $ver` - the new value for selected node